# Jquery draggable doesn't work

Tags: javascript

In one of my web pages, there is a div containing an image wider than the div (container). In order to view it completely, it is to be moved by mouse.

My problem arises when, moving it to the right, and to other directions as well, it goes on beyond the edge instead of stopping at the end of the shot.
 
I made some attempts:

```
{containment: "parent"}
```

When the image is moved, it jumps then stopping random.
Also, when dragging the image, the cursor remains the one defined by (css) ? and does not change, though I stated:

```
{cursor: "move"}
```

Here is the link with the page malfunction:
http://www.parcomonza.org/v4-0/mappa-parco_pc.htm

Comment: where is the draggable item? Could you provide a codepen it is much easier to help?

Answer (score 0):

If you define a containment the image is only allowed to be dragged inside this element. This does not work for you because your **secondaimmagine** is bigger than the containment.
The solution is to remove the containment.

```
$( "#secondaimmagine" ).draggable({cursor: "move"});
```

your parent div **mappaparcoDIV** handles the overflow, which happens when you drag the image, with the following css rule correctly.

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Answer (score 0):

I know if I cancel "containment" I can move "secondaimmagine" but that doesn't stop move at the overflow until I have "mappaparcoDIV" with "overflow:hidden"